# USB-C headphones, use as input and output at the same time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, microphone, usb-c

First some background information:

- I am running Ubuntu 19.04
- Laptop: Dell XPS 13 9360
- Earbuds: Pixel USB-C earbuds (wired)
- Using pulse audio with pulseEffects

Most of the time when I plug in the earbuds in via the Thunderbolt port, after a bit of work the audio output switches to my earbuds. However, the issue is using the earbuds as both an output and an input simultaneously.

In the default Ubuntu settings page with audio coming out the earbuds, if I switch my microphone to the "headset microphone" the output audio switches back to my built-in speakers but the microphone appears to be working correctly. The reverse is true, if the microphone is working correctly, and I try to switch the output device to the earbuds, the input device switches back to the built-in microphone.

If I use the pulseAudio volume control, under the configuration tab, the profiles shown for the earbuds are very inconsistent. Just unplugging and plugging back in will change what is available. These are the combinations I've seen so far:

- "Stereo output"
- "Multichannel output"
- "Multichannel input"
- "off"

--

- "Digital Stereo (IEC958) output"
- "Multichannel input"
- "off"

--

- "Digital Stereo (IEC958) output + Multichannel input"
- "Digital Stereo (IEC958) output"
- "Multichannel input"
- "off"

--

- "Analog mono input"
- "off"

--

- "Multichannel output"
- "Multichannel input"
- "Digital Stereo (IEC958) output"
- "Analog stereo output + Analog Mono input"
- "off"

[pulseAudio volume control, image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZWuY.png)

The profiles with the plus in the name seem to do what I want, however, these seem to be the rarest and are almost never the default selected.

**How can I make the profiles more consistent or create my own profile that is loaded by default when this device is detected?**